# How to use Lights and Shadows in Ursina

Tags: python, shadow, light, ursina

I'm new to Ursina engine, And I'm creating horror game, I'm trying to make a Flashlight for player (First Person Controller) but I don't know exactly how to use lights, And I don't know what is the best light for me, And I want to add limited range of light to the Flashlight, And make it looks to same place that player looks at
Also I want to know if there's a way to disable shadows for some Entity.

I tried to use every light in Ursina and here what I got:
1.DirectionalLight: when I run game light comes from specific position and I couldn't change it
2.PointLight: when I run light came from default position and it's light everywhere (not looking at specific place)
3.SpotLight: when I run everything becomes black and I can't see anything
4.AmpientLight: when I run nothing happens to the game (everything looks as normal)
I didn't know how to handle with shadows of Entities

Thanks for Help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.